# executing command through popen in linux

Tags: c++, linux, popen

I am executing commands through popen(), system() in my c++ application. Every command is executing successfully and getting results as expected. **But whenever I am trying any command with lpstat (displays information of printers and jobs), getting no results.**

Note : I take same code in my test app, and it runs fine. lpstat gives results as expected. 
**So is there anything, which is blocking to execute lpstat command ?**

Thanks in advance !!!

I am calling this method in main, passing command "lpstat -W all" or any lpstat command with diffrent options not executing. Wherever other commands are working fine.

here is my code Sample :

**

```
std::string ExecQueryRun(std::string lcCommand)
{
    std::string Result;   
    FILE * stream;
    if (lcCommand.empty())
        return "Bash Command is empty ";

    char ReadBuffer[MAX_BUFFER + 1] = {0};
    lcCommand.append(" 2>&1");
    stream = popen(lcCommand.c_str(), "r");
    if (stream)
    {
        while (!feof(stream))
        {
            if (fgets(ReadBuffer, MAX_BUFFER, stream) != NULL)
            {
                Result.append(ReadBuffer);
            }
        }
        pclose(stream);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "popen fails in ExecQueryRun " << endl;
    }


    return Result;
}

void main()
{
   cout << "Result :: " << ExecQueryRun("lpstat -W all") << endl;

   /* some other code here */

  getchar();
  return;
}
```

**

Comment: Show us some code, too?

Comment: updated question with my code sample

Comment: And what happens in the unsuccessful case? What is `lcCommand`?

Comment: The code you've shown works for me with the same `lpstat` command. Did you forget to print the result in `main`? Make a [mcve]

Comment: It would help if you do `perror` in case of failure or at least also print out `errno`. That may give you an idea about what goes wrong.

Comment: Unrelated: You could simplify your read loop to: `while(fgets(ReadBuffer, MAX_BUFFER, stream) != nullptr) {
            Result.append(ReadBuffer);
        }`

Comment: @TedLyngmo  : Yes I have printed the output in main.

Comment: @DanielJunglas : Yes i will try this.

Comment: @ket You could update your question to include the missing lines of code that would make it a [mcve].

Comment: Also try to rework your reading loop as `while(fgets(stream, ...)){ ... }; if(ferror(stream)) error_message();`

Comment: Does your application runs as a different user / with different privileges / in setuid/setgid mode / with a different path?

Comment: Then see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/565254/308316) for an explanation and possible fix.

Comment: @mosvy: Thanks for your help. yes my application is running with sudo mode, hence it was not working, but when I ran without sudo privilege, its working. However, we need to run application in sudo privilege. Can you please suggest?

Comment: It's already in the link I suggested you above: `uid_t euid = geteuid(); setresuid(euid, euid, euid);` before the `popen()`. Of course, it could be that the effective user you run as simply hasn't the right privileges; try adding it to the `lpadmin` group (that is a problem more for unix.se than here).

Comment: @mosvy :  Got solution. Thanks again. As u said, adding root user to lpadmin group solves it.